# Confirm dialog (Alert) inside AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I have a long process running inside AsyncTask but it might need to confirm something from user while processing. I know how I can show a confirm dialog but how can I retrieve the output and keep wait till use confirms?

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               boolean output = ConfirmUser(message);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say that it is bad idea. If you need a confirmation from user, you better split your AsyncTask in two parts: do some part first, then inside *onPostExecute()* you can show dialog (because it is running on ui thread) and, depending on user action, launch second AsyncTask.

If you still want to do it one AsyncTask, you can do it like this:

```
final BlockingQueue<Boolean> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Boolean>(1);
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Assuming you have ConfirmUser method which returns boolean
        queue.add(ConfirmUser(message));
    }
});


Boolean result = null;
try {
    // This will block until something will be added to the queue
    result = queue.take();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // deal with it
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks, btw splitting the AsyncTask is not possible with current design but I will think for better approach if possible or needed.

Comment: One thing to ask, when InterruptedException will be thrown ?

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :(

Comment: Xmen, InterruptedException will be thrown if somebody will call interrupt() on Thread which is doing AsyncTask. This exception can be thrown when you are doing something related to locks or sleep (for example Thread.sleep also throws that exception)